# How to correctly add records to jpa onetomany join table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm developing a filing system where I have 3 tables. PROJECTS table consists of projectid, project name and other details (see below). This is an existing class and populated schema and I do not want to modify this part of the application if possible.

Folders table (Called ProjectClassification) consists of folderid and foldername and is the owning side of a unidirectional onetomany relationship.

Project_Folders is a join table. I'm using JPA 2.0 (EclipseLink) and JSF 2.0 as my web framework.

My basic problem is I can't add duplicate records to the join table using a merge operation. MERGE is good for adding records until the owning key already exists, after which point it will only update the join table. I know this is the way it's supposed to work but I need to add new records even if there's a duplicate of the owning key. This will allow me to store different projects in the same folder.

I've looked through some other questions here such as:

[onetomany unidirectional with jointable setup using jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374334/onetomany-unidirectional-with-jointable-setup-using-jpa)

This says what is needed to add one entity to the other in a join table but i need to know more about how to correctly persist or merge the added entity to the database.

The folder entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECTCLASSIFICATIONS")
public class ProjectClassifications implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int proclassid;
private int projectid;

private String classification;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "PROJECT_CLASSF_JOIN",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "proclassid", referencedColumnName = "proclassid"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "projectid", referencedColumnName = "projectid", unique = true))

private Collection<Projects> projects;

public ProjectClassifications() {

}

public ProjectClassifications(String classification) {
    this.classification = classification;
}

public ProjectClassifications(int proclassid, int projectid) {
    this.proclassid = proclassid;

    projects = new ArrayList<Projects>();
}

public ProjectClassifications(Projects newProject) {

    projects = new ArrayList<Projects>();

}

public void addProject(Projects newProject) {
    if(!getProjects().contains(newProject))
    getProjects().add(newProject);
}

....
....
```

The Project entity class is a pre existing code and I do not want to modify at all if possible:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECTS")
public class Projects {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int projectid;

private String projectName;
private String projectDescription;

@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date startDate;
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date endDate;
private String commnts;



// foreign keys to parent tables
private int fk_countryid;
private int fk_companyid;
private int fk_employeeid;

@ManyToOne(optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "countryid")
private Country country;
....
....
```

I then use two html select lists to select values for projectid and proclassid which call the following methoid  using a JSF managed bean:

```
public String makeProClassRecord() {
   newProClass = new ProjectClassifications(proclassid, projectid);
   newProject = proServ.findByProjectId(projectid);
   newProClass.addProject(newProject);


facade.update(newProClass);
//facade.save(newProClass);
    return showProclass();
}
```

My questions are:

1) Is MERGE the correct operation used to add records into a join table?

2) Is there a way to add records that contain duplicate keys (foreign keys represented as new records in the join table) using MERGE?

3) Should PERSIST be used to achieve question 2?

4) Would it be better to create an entity for the join table itself and simply use a PERSIST method to insert the records?

Many thanks

Comment: why is there a field of type Set marked as OneToOne?! You don't add objects to a join table ... you simply set the relation (on both sides when bidirectional) and then persist/merge depending on the state of your object

Comment: Thanks Neil. The OnetoOne field was a prior error which was on the program before I started working on it. I removed this and it does not influence my problem one way or the other. Normally I wouldn't use a join table, but in this case I might need one? As mentioned in my question, I don't want to interfere with the existing CRUD operations of the Projects entity. I simply want to create a filing system and leave everything else intact. So doesn't that suggest I need a unidirectional onetomany relationship and a join table is the right way to achieve that?

Comment: whether you call persist or merge is to do with what state the object is in. Is it persistent? detached? transient (i.e not yet persisted)?

Comment: That's very useful to know. I already have a transient field in the Projects entity. I think my options are limited to detached states and that's why I must use merge for the join table case. Persist creates new objects for the Projects and ProjectClassifications entities but not the join table (which is what I want). Also wouldn't persist  result in IntegrityViolationConstraint because of a duplicate key entry? So aren't I compelled to using merge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this myself a couple of weeks ago and thought of sharing the answer. Instead of doing merge or persist operations on any of the target entities, I created a Join table and unidirectional OneToMany relationship from the Project entity to the below ProjectFileSystem join table entity and simply did the persist operation using that entity.  I need to add duplicate folders for different projects (or store many projects under a single folder item) so it seems more efficient to do the CRUD operations in the actual join table entity rather than from the target entity. Hope this helps:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROFOLDERSYS_JOIN")

public class ProjectFileSystem implements Serializable{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int foldersysid;

private int proclassid;

private int projectid;

private String projectName;

private String folderName;

public ProjectFileSystem() {

}

public ProjectFileSystem(int proclassid, int projectid,
        String projectName, String folderName) {
    this.proclassid = proclassid;
    this.projectid = projectid;
    this.projectName = projectName;
    this.folderName = folderName;
}


// getters and setters
}
```

The method in the bean would be:

```
public String makeProSys() {
    newProSys = new ProjectFileSystem(proclassid, projectid,     classification, projectName);

    newProject = proServ.findByProjectId(projectid);
    projectName = newProject.getProjectName();
    newProSys.setProjectName(projectName);

    newProClass = facade.findByContactId(proclassid);
    classification = newProClass.getClassification();
    newProSys.setFolderName(classification);

    profilFacade.save(newProSys);
    return showProSys();
}
```